# Option menu and overflow menu issue

Tags: android

I am developing one application in which I'm using `Sherlock Actionbar` library for 4.0 effect in lower device, in this app there are 5 items in Menu and it is appear at option menu. When I press menu in actionbar its getting me the item list correctly but when I click on Overflow menu button(hardware menu)it doesn't give me any option.I need all items in both menu as it is.

I have tried with `android:showAsAction="never"` and it appears in overflow menu but not in option menu that appear in `actionbar`. and if I do `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` then it only appears in option menu in action bar not in Overflow menu so can you please find the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you overridden your `OnCreateOptionsMenu()`? You need this for menu button support.
This is mine:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, ((MenuWrapper) menu).unwrap());
    return true;
}
```

Edit: and `onOptionsItemSelected()`, too?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_logout:
        logout();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        openSettings();
        return true;
    case android.R.id.home:
        getSlidingMenu().toggle();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
   //getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  
 }

Comment: Wait... the overflow icon is actually showing up on devices with a menu button? Because I just realised that is not supposed to happen. You're supposed to get a menu on the center bottom on those devices

Comment: no,I dont wont to get menu in center bottom and its not a matter that display alignment, issue is its not display menu in overflow

Comment: Yes, I get that, my point is that that is not default behaviour, and you may have broken something somewhere.

Comment: What is your `android:targetSdkVersion`

Comment: My targetted version is 15

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21255/discussion-between-critical-questionnaire-and-robin-kanters)

Comment: Yeah I don't have time to chat right now, I think someone else needs to step in here